# How can I control a dropdown's visible text's position?

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown that I'm looking to enlarge without effecting the text and ensuring the right hand down arrow remains at the full hieght of the element.

I've tried adding padding but this effects the right side:

[Dropdown with padding http://hoctordesign.com/dropdown2.png](http://hoctordesign.com/dropdown2.png)

I've tired adding height but I can't vertically align the text:

[Dropdown with height http://hoctordesign.com/dropdown.png](http://hoctordesign.com/dropdown.png)

Anyone solved this before?

Thanks,
Denis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it would be better to use a custom element that acts like a select box.

Here is a nice one using jQuery

[Select Box replacement](http://www.brainfault.com/2007/07/23/select-box-replacement/)

Answer (score 2):

This is browser-dependent behaviour. Each browser applies css to form controls differently.

The best breakdown of what you can do (that I've come across) is at http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200701/styling_form_controls_with_css_revisited/. And the most relevant section is http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/select-single/

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. Great article, it's nice to see how it looks in so many browsers at once, after reading it looks like I have to leave it alone or use JavaScript.

Comment: basically, yeah. Fortunately most of the jQuery plugins for select box replacements don't break things completely if Javascript is disabled. Just be sure to test things with JS disabled to see if things still function properly (if not prettily)